# Did the author forget to use 'if' or I'm missing some literary style

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I completed reading a short novel ["**A Little Princess**"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Little_Princess) written by *Frances Hodgson Burnett*.

The servant, "Ram Dass" says the following while planning to change the protagonist's(Sara Crewe) room from its shabby state(page 131, 4<sup>th</sup> paragraph, fifth line):

> The vision she related told what this miserable room **might be in it
>   had comforts in it**.

In my opinion, the correct usage should have been:

> ... might be in **if** it had comforts in it.

I'll quote the whole conversation here in case one has not yet read/heard-of the novel:

> "It is true that the first thought was mine, Sahib," he said, "though
>   it was naught but a fancy. I am fond of this child; we are both
>   lonely. It is her way to relate her visions to her secret friends.
>   Being sad one night, I lay close to the open skylight and listened.
>   **The vision she related told what this miserable room might be in it had comforts in it**. She seemed to see it as she talked, and she grew
>   cheered and warmed as she spoke. Then ...

Comment: Hello!  I see you've posted an answer, and I'm glad you were able to solve your problem.  That said, I've voted to close as Too Localized.  I'm afraid that a question about a typo isn't likely to help other users in the future.

Comment: @snailplane I chose to vote as localized too. I had some other doubts too in the novel. I'll cross-reference them with the text on wikisource and edit this question.

Comment: Just to be clear, the original example sentence with the typo in it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [entire chapter](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Little_Princess/Chapter_14) on [Wikipedia's wikisource](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Little_Princess/Chapter_14) and apparently, the actual sentence does have **if** present in there:

> The vision she related told what this miserable room might be **if** it had comforts in it.

I have the edition published in 1994 by Wordsworth Editions.